# Javascript TimeZone issue

Tags: javascript, timezone

I am using Bootstrap date picker when I pick date 05-03-2015 then it returns same date but when I change the time zone of the system and picks the same date but it returns 04-03-2015. I'm converting the date string format to this format 'yyyy-mm-dd' using below function.

```
  $scope.convertDateToDestinationFormat = function () {
            var dateValue = new Date('Thu Oct 28 1965 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)');
            var monthsInt = ("0" + (dateValue.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var daysInt = ("0" + (dateValue.getDate())).slice(-2);
            return dateValue.getFullYear() + "-" + monthsInt + "-" + daysInt;
        };
```

Comment: which is the plugin used

Comment: I am not using any plugin just I'm traying to convert this date string 'Thu Oct 28 1965 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)' to this '28-10-1965' but it returns '27-10-1965' when i changed system time zone otherwise it works fine...

Comment: remove the timezone part from the date string then parse it

Comment: I have update the above question..

Comment: So, changing the time zone pulled the time into another day.  Is that surprising to you? It shouldn't be.  Midnight today, minus 1 hour, is 11PM yesterday.